# Is my "viewDidLoad" being called everytime I open the same window after closing it first?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

Hello i have a very simple question, I have initialized some variables and started the motion manager updates on the "viewDidLoad" method, but after i finish using it I am closing the window and returning to the previews one. My question is whether the method is being called everytime i open that window trough a segue in the storyboard. (Since the description says it does it when it loads it to memory not to the screen)

I am closing the window by telling that window that the previous one is its delegate like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Drawing"])
    {
        DrawingViewController *temp = segue.destinationViewController;
        temp.delegate = self;
    }

}
```

and then when the user clicks the closing button in the new window it tells the delegate (the previous screen) to close him:

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate DrawingViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}
```

This is the closing method:

```
- (void)DrawingViewControllerDidCancel: (DrawingViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Oh and if someone would be so kind to tell me why is it that by calling self i am closing the other window, (Because i think self refers to the delegate not to the one that i want to close).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some log statements in the viewDidLoad method, this will be easy enough to find out for yourself. You can't expect a view controller that has been dismissed to be hanging around in memory - it could get unloaded at any time due to a low memory situation. You've even *called* it `temp` ;)

`dismissModalViewController` is passed along the view controller chain, you can call it on the modal controller itself or the presenting controller, it has the same effect. The currently presented modal view controller is dismissed.

From the documentation:

> If you present several modal view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of modal view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

Comment: ooo you are a genious, haha or im very stupid lol. anyways it seems it is loading it everytime i click it. About the second thing, so that means that "dismissModalViewController" will dismiss ANY modal view controller that is currently active and being displayed right?

Comment: Oh and i forgot, Somehow everytime i start this window my drawings seems to get messed up, like the first time i start it, i use the motion manager to draw some stuff, then i close it, then i start it again and it draws but the drawings seem more spaced, and if i close and repeat they are even more spaced, any idea what might be causing this? i am using a NSTimer to execute the drawing method everytime the window "will appear".

Comment: The drawing thing should be a new question. As for the first, yes, but you have to call the method in the modal controller or one of the controllers presenting it.

Comment: okay thanks, i figured out why it was having such a weird behaviour, seems that i was creating new instances of device motion manager because the "viewdidunload" doesnt actually unloads it when i close the screen haha like you said.